# Java Multidimensional array with excell file and JFileChooser?

Tags: java, file, multidimensional-array

Ok, so basically, my head hurts and I'm stuck with this now. So I have a program that has an open button and a text area. When you use hte open button, you an open a csv file made in excell. My program is supposed to open a file, append it into the text area, but then I'm trying to store all of the values into a multi dimensional array so that I can then use another class to have methods for calculating things such as the highest and lowest value. So far, I have just started by trying to do the highest value, but I am having no luck. The file opens and appends, but the max value is getting some kind of error. If anyone can help me solve this I would highly apprciate it.

main class

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.TextArea;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;


public class task3 extends JFrame {

    public static JPanel contentPane;
    public JTextField txtOpen;
    public JButton btnOpen;
    public static TextArea textArea;
    int rows = 9, columns = 1441; //Columns up and down, rows across. Number of rows and columns in excell file.
    double[][] data = new double[rows][columns]; //Array to hold the rows and columns. 

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    task3 frame = new task3();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public task3() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 560, 350);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        btnOpen = new JButton("Open");
        btnOpen.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {


                try{
                    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser(); //File Chooser
                    chooser.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Excell CSV Files", "csv"));
                    chooser.removeChoosableFileFilter(chooser.getAcceptAllFileFilter()); //Filters for csv file

                    //Get the file
                    int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(task3.contentPane); 
                    File file;
                    if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {    
                        file = chooser.getSelectedFile();  
                    }
                    else{
                        file = null;
                    }


                    //Read the file into variable
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                    String line = in.readLine();

                    while(line != null){
                        task3.textArea.append(line + "\n");
                        line = in.readLine(); //Print out into text area
                    }

                    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
                        //Use a temporary array to hold the rows in whilst the data is split.
                        String array [] = line.split(","); //Split the data up using the commas.
                        for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++){
                            //Take the rows and columns and convert them into a double so they can be saved into the array.
                            data[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(array[j]);
                        }
                    }

                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                double max = task3Methods.Max(data);
                textArea.append("\n\nmax is: "+max);
            }
        });
        btnOpen.setBounds(256, 22, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnOpen);

        txtOpen = new JTextField();
        txtOpen.setBounds(61, 23, 174, 20);
        contentPane.add(txtOpen);
        txtOpen.setColumns(10);

        textArea = new TextArea();
        textArea.setBounds(27, 57, 507, 245);
        contentPane.add(textArea);
    }
}
```

methods class

```
public class task3Methods {

    public static double Max(double[][] data){

        double temp;

        double high = Double.MIN_VALUE;  //State this variable hold the largest possible double in the file.

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){ //Loop through the data.
            for(int j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++){
                temp = data[i][j];
                if(temp > high){ //If a number in the array is larger than the current highest value...
                    high = temp; //Store the new highest value.
                }               
            }
        }

        return high;
    }
}
```

Here's a link to the excell file I am using in drop box
https://www.dropbox.com/s/62ssjoph2z6vmv3/Temperature_Log.csv

Sorry, here's the exact error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at task3$2.mouseClicked(task3.java:86)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

And in the text area, instead of saying like 
Max = 21.5456 or whatever, it says max is: 4.9E-324

Comment: `"...but the max value is getting some kind of error."` -- when asking about an error here, you **always** want to show us the error message itself. A careful reading of this message often shows us (and you) the cause of the problem and can help lead to a solution. Please post this for us.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, I am a full blown noob, I have added the error :)

Comment: No problem, but I was right, the error message is key. Please look at this line, `java.lang.NullPointerException at task3$2.mouseClicked(task3.java:86)`. You will want to tell us which line is line 86 of task3.java. A variable that you are trying to use on that line is null.

Comment: Also, you never want to use a MouseListener on a JButton. Instead use an ActionListener as they work much better with buttons.

Comment: One problem I see is that if the user declines the JFileChooser and the File variable is set to null, you still try to read it. You should pack the file reading code *inside* of your if block.

Comment: Ahh yes, the mouse event was done using windows builder, not very great, it's just the way they are trying to teach us at the moment. It's saying that the string called line is null, but that's used with the reader to store the data being read.

Comment: They are teaching you to add MouseListeners to JButtons? Really? I have to question the wisdom of your instructors.

Comment: My instructor is a useless douche rod. That's why I've been here asking questions with silly mistakes like mis placed code or MouseListeners over ActionListeners. Unfortunately, without someone to teach me properly, I don't know how else to go about these problems. Thankfully, there's some nice people on here who can really help. :)

Comment: While you'll find this site good for answering specific questions, we're no substitute for your instructor, or if you don't get along with your instructor, then with your studying the Java tutorials and your book. We are only able to answer specific questions, but the basic knowledge of Java must be gained by you through your diligent study and practice. Luck.

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs in this section:

```
while (line != null) {
   A.textArea.append(line + "\n");
   line = in.readLine(); // Print out into text area
}

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
   // Use a temporary array to hold the rows in whilst the data is split.
   String array[] = line.split(","); // Split the data up using the commas.
   for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
      // Take the rows and columns and convert them into a double so they can be saved into the array.
      data[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(array[j]);
    }
}
```

After the last iteration of your while loop,`in.readLine()` will always return null.  You later then call `line.split(",")`, which is causing the `NullPointerException`.  If I understand your code, you do not want to use `line.split()` here, since you are appending all of the file's text to `A.textArea`.  You should instead do one of two things, either store the text in an array as you are reading from the file, or use `A.textArea.getText()` to access the rows previously read.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still learning atm. So By trying to split the string line after already using it, it's null. Instead, I should say 
String newArray[] = textarea.getText().split 
?

Comment: `textarea.getText.split(",")` will return an array of Strings where each entry is the text immediately preceding a comma.  If that's what you're aiming to do here, that should work.

Comment: Ok, that fixed the null pointer error, but it's still not working, now I get an error on the line that says 
data[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(array[j]);
saying that   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Timestamp"

Comment: It's pretty self descriptive.  You're calling `parseDouble`, which attempts to take a String along the lines of "30.20" and convert it to a Double.  The exception is happening because "Timestamp" can't be parsed to a Double.  I don't know the format of the file you're reading in, but it looks like you're reading a header row perhaps?  p.s. I can't understate the importance of a debugger in problems like this.

Comment: It's an excell file. In the first box it says like time stamp, the second box has a sensor name like 4EZ57 and then like a bunch of readings which are like 19746 21945 16473

Comment: So when you read the first line, you shouldn't store the first two values in the array of data that you're later trying to parse as a double.

Comment: How do I tell the program to not count the first two values? That would solve everything from the looks of it.

Comment: Why not start the second for loop at 2?

Comment: I have no idea how to do that x)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not going to continue spoon feeding your entire homework assignment to you.  Please accept the answer if I answered your initial question and open another one for other problems.